# Gnome shell failure. Extensions not working

Tags: gnome, 20.04, login, gnome-shell-extension

All of the sudden, Gnome shell extensions stopped working.

Anyone know what could be the issue or where to start looking for it?

I am using `Ubuntu 20.04` and `GNOME Shell 3.36.4`.

Here are some logs:

```
Sep 30 20:48:14 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: Will monitor session 11
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: Failed to create file /run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions: Error opening file “/run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions”: File exists
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: **
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: ERROR:gmenu-tree.c:3776:preprocess_layout_info: assertion failed: (!directory->preprocessed)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: Bail out! ERROR:gmenu-tree.c:3776:preprocess_layout_info: assertion failed: (!directory->preprocessed)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 6
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: == Stack trace for context 0x557e6bc49920 ==
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #0   557e6c4714b0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js:598 (184862b91448 @ 131)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #1   557e6c4713e8 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js:407 (184862b8f8f8 @ 807)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #2   557e6c471338 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js:681 (184862b7f9e8 @ 21)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #3   557e6c471270 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:167 (65d60646a0 @ 571)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #4   7ffc6cce8f40 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:349 (65d6064bc8 @ 361)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #5   7ffc6cce9a30 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:599 (65d606a718 @ 551)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #6   7ffc6ccea470 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27 (65d60068f8 @ 350)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #7   557e6c4711c8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:574 (65d606a6a0 @ 494)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #8   557e6c471138 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:608 (65d606a790 @ 67)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #9   557e6c4710a8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:639 (65d606a970 @ 57)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #10   557e6c470fe8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:56 (65d6064358 @ 268)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #11   557e6c470f48 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:257 (1c6c385d5cb8 @ 1181)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #12   557e6c470e98 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:146 (1c6c385d5ad8 @ 308)
Sep 30 20:48:15 ___ gnome-shell[19745]: #13   557e6c470e10 i   <main>:1 (1c6c3858d178 @ 48)
Sep 30 20:50:11 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Sep 30 20:50:11 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Will monitor session 12
Sep 30 20:50:12 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Sep 30 20:50:12 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Failed to create file /run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions: Error opening file “/run/user/1000/gnome-shell-disable-extensions”: File exists
Sep 30 20:50:12 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Extension user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com already installed in /home/____/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com will not be loaded
Sep 30 20:50:12 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Sep 30 20:50:13 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Sep 30 20:50:14 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: GNOME Shell started at Wed Sep 30 2020 20:50:12 ____
Sep 30 20:50:14 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Registering session with GDM
Sep 30 20:50:14 ___ gnome-shell[22177]: Error connecting to Nautilus
```

Comment: You've installed some third-party extensions that are probably causing the problem. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and I'll take a look. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.